# Tracking execution of lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I have a lambda that can be executed from various accounts. I wish to track how long the lambda executed for when executed by different accounts.  AWS X-ray gives my the duration for which lambda executed by I can't corelate that information to the caller of the lambda function.

Is there a way to link the duration of execution of lambda function to caller to the function?

Comment: How is the Lambda called?  Do you have separate credentials for the calls?  Are you calling it directly (i.e. like using the cli to do `aws lambda invoke`) or are you using something like API gateway?

Comment: Its being triggered via action on DynamoDB streams. The streams is enabled on a dynamodb table which is backing an API Gateway. A call to the API Gateway endpoint directly writes to dynamodb table which triggers a record in streams which invokes the Lambda.

Comment: Ultimately you'll need a different user per call somehow.  That could be a different API endpoint or other indication of the user (i.e. header value).  You'll need to track that through DynamoDB (i.e. have a "user" field") and then passed to the Lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the parameter(s) to identify the accounts on your lambda function, you may use "Annotations and metadata" feature of aws x-ray. After you make configuration it is going to be shown on your x-ray traces.

[please check for official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-concepts.html#xray-concepts-annotations)

Edit: Since you are using java; you may try the example [code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-segment.html#xray-sdk-java-segment-annotations)