# Searching AWS X-ray filtered on annotations

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

I have enabled X-ray tracing for my AWS Lambda function and from my code base and an annotation that captures the accountId. The AWX X-Ray [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-gettingdata.html#xray-api-traces) for getting data from X-ray mentions that annotation associated with X-ray trace are indexed

I am annotating my traces with an accountId. I wish to retrieve all traces having `accountId = '12345'`

I have confirmed that my traces have my required annotation. I found this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-filters.html) but I am just not sure of how to apply these filters from cli.

Snippet from result of a trace using the `aws xray get-trace-summaries --start-time <start_time> --end-time <end_time>`

```
"Annotations": {
                "lambdaAccountId": [
                    {
                        "AnnotationValue": {
                            "StringValue": "12345"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Comment: Did you get any results on aws console ? Executing the query such as service("your-lambda-service-name") and annotation.lambdaAccountId = "12345"

Comment: Yes. Adding `annotation.lambdaAccountId = "12345"` in the console search, gives all traces with the annotation. However, not sure how to use this filter from cli

Comment: Another option could be; aws xray get-trace-summaries --start-time=1587398166 --end-time=1587398566 --filter-expression "annotation.lambdaAccountId=\"12345\"" aws cli documentation doesn't provide a lot about the example usages. 

edit: you need to escape double quotes

Comment: I think this issue is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61299691/2188922 - please let me know if it works - i will update the answer in the given link. anyone may need it in the future.

Comment: Its kind-off related... But the above command works... You can move it to "Answers" and I accept it.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aws xray get-trace-summaries --start-time=1587398166 --end-time=1587398566 --filter-expression "annotation.lambdaAccountId=\"12345\""
```

would do the work. Here is the link with some [sample queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-guide.pdf)